# Combining multiple values (unique and different) into one column to based on unique value

Tags: arcgis-pro, geoprocessing, table

I have a table consisting of two columns (1) unique values (some multiple times) and (2) values (unique and different) - I want to create a table that will contain two columns (1) unique values (no dupes) and (2) multiple values separated by a comma and without dupes.
[image]

I have tried the Pivot Table and Transpose functions in ArcGIS Pro, both of these functions don't provide me with the output I need. I've also tried google but most queries are based on multiple columns and their solutions link back to using Pivot tables and the Transpose functions. I've even tried to look at some Python scripts to work out some method, but alas I don't have much experience in Python scripting.

I'm hoping that I can do this process in ArcGIS Pro 2.8 and not move back and forth using different software (e.g. Excel).

Comment: At the moment your tables are unreadable.

Comment: I follow the tags, so not sure why... I clipped it as an image so now it can be readable.

Comment: This could be done easily with a cursor and a dictionary in your python window, would you like to try that?

Comment: @MichaelStimson at this moment I'm game for anything... although I am not well versed in dictionary but am familiar with cursors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS Pro's Python interpreter comes bundled with all kinds of handy data science packages, like [pandas - Python Data Analysis Library](https://pandas.pydata.org/).  The [Data Access module - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/what-is-the-data-access-module-.htm) has several functions for moving data back and forth between ArcGIS and NumPy.  The following code

```py
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

in_table = '' # name of table view or path to table
out_table = '' # path to output table

df = pd.DataFrame(
        arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(
            in_table,
            ("ID", "Zone"),
            null_value=''
        )
    )
grouped = df.groupby("ID")["Zone"].apply(set).apply(",".join)
records = grouped.to_frame().to_records(column_dtypes=("U255"))
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable(records, out_table)

print(*arcpy.da.SearchCursor(out_table, "*"), sep="\n")
```

yields:

```py
(1, 1, 'Commercial,Residential')
(2, 2, 'Commercial')
(3, 3, 'Residential')
(4, 4, 'Commercial,Industry')
```

If you want to avoid using pandas and stick with ArcPy, this is a perfect case for using [defaultdict - collections — Container datatypes - Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

The following code

```py
import arcpy
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

in_table = '' # name of table view or path to table
out_table = '' # path to output table

grouped = defaultdict(set)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table, ("ID", "Zone")) as cur:
    for id, zone in cur:
        grouped[id].add(zone)

records = np.rec.fromrecords(
    [(k, ",".join(i for i in v if i)) for k,v in grouped.items()],
    names="ID,Zone"
)
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable(records, out_table)

print(*arcpy.da.SearchCursor(out_table, "*"), sep="\n")
```

yields

```py
(1, 1, 'Commercial,Residential')
(2, 2, 'Commercial')
(3, 3, 'Residential')
(4, 4, 'Commercial,Industry')
```

I find [numpy.core.records.fromrecords -- NumPy v1.24 Manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.core.records.fromrecords.html) and [NumPyArrayToTable - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/numpyarraytotable.htm) as a great combination for creating new ArcGIS tables and populating them when you already have a structured data set in Python.

Comment: The python script (without pandas) gave back an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 14, in <listcomp>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Comment: The python script (with pandas) ran through without errors, it also provided the required output. Note if anyone is using the above panda script - it puts a "0" in if the field is <NULL>. Might have to start learning/reading about python pandas and dictionary. Thanks.

Comment: @Pikachun, I updated the code so the defaultdict will handle it, and I changed the pandas approach to use empty string instead of 0.  Try them both out.

Comment: -@bixb0012 - Python script (no pandas) worked and provided the output exactly how I need it. Python script (with pandas) worked too, originally with a NULL it produced "0, Commercial" now it outputs ", Commercial" - maybe it needs an if statement to check if it's NULL don't added a comma. I will close the question off as this has answered my query in Python ArcGIS Pro 2.8 - Thank you. (not sure if you want to update the Python script (with pandas) NULL comma issue.)

Answer (score 2):

*Note the answer below was written *before* the OP edited the question to note they are using ArcGIS Pro 2.8.  I am leaving this answer up even though will not work for 2.8 as it may be useful for users with the same need who have moved to ArcGIS Pro 3x*

If you have ArcGIS Pro 3.x, this is possible using the [Summary Statistics (Analysis)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm) tool with "Concatenate" as the statistic.  Note: Concatenate is *not* available in ArcGIS Pro 2.x

> **Concatenate** — The values for the specified field will be concatenated. The values can be separated using the **Concatenation Separator** parameter.

To avoid duplicates, you need to run it twice, once to get rid of dupes (use Count as the statistic), then again on the previous output with Concatenate.

Examples from [How To: Concatenate field values using a Case Field in ArcGIS Pro](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000028144) (note includes duplicates, see above to avoid)

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Yes, I  did read that ArcGIS Pro 3 had that function but alas my company has not migrated to the newer version, until then I need a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

As you have some experience with python this should help:

```py
ExistingTable = r'c:\path\to\table'
OutputTable   = r'c:\path\to\output\table'

AllValues = {} # new, empty dictionary

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ExistingTable,['ID','Zone']) as sCur:
    for sRow in sCur:
        if sRow[0] in AllValues:
            # add to the existing value(s)
            AllValues[sRow[0]] = "{},{}".format(AllValues[sRow[0]],sRow[1])
        else:
            # create a new key:value pair
            AllValues[sRow[0]] = sRow[1]

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(OutputTable) as iCur:
    for ThisKey in AllValues:
        iCur.insertRow((ThisKey,AllValues[ThisKey]))
```

This code is for ArcGIS Desktop, hopefully Pro isn't much different.

A [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) looks like a list except it stores information in key:value pairs; keys must be unique but values don't need to be. This code starts with an empty dictionary and then checks to see if the key exists, if so append the value, if not set the value for the key. Note that apart from being unique keys can be numeric or string.

Comment: I ran the code and it came back with an error. "Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 6, in <module> TypeError: function missing required argument 'field_names' (pos 2)" maybe python is different in Desktop and Pro.

I did some (air)research about the error and modified the code (added in the actual field names) and still came back with an error. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're right, ArcGIS Pro requires the field names; they're optional in Desktop. Apart from that the use of the cursor is the same as https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm what error did you get with the modified code?

Comment: One of the rows in output will say 2 commercial, commercial.  I think it's better to use defaultdict(set) or (list) and set on it.

Comment: @MichaelStimson managed to get the script to work in ArcGIS Pro. I added in the fields and needed another open-close bracket on the last line of code and it ran through. As indicated by FelixIP it retains the dupes in the zone column.